# Error: ToolBar theme and Dark theme

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme

I am using the current style and theme for my toolbar and using a support library. I am extending AppCompatActivity rather than the normal activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>
```

I am getting the error and below is the stacktrace,

```
Process: com.random.simplenotes, PID: 2176
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams
                      at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.applyInsets(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:172)
                      at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:317)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Application terminated.
```

Main Activity

The problem occurred when I tried to apply a Dark Theme.`parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"` For this attribute how do I know which themes will work and which ones will not ?  and what should be done to apply the dark theme which does not give any error ?

Let me know what else code is needed and I will edit the question accordingly.

**EDIT 1** 
As requested in the comments, I have added the Activity onCreate() method

Initialization

```
 DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
    ListView notesView;
    CustomCursor dataCursor;
    int ROW_NUMBER;
    Cursor passCursor;
    Toolbar bar;



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        passCursor = dbhelper.fetchAllNotes();
        dataCursor = new CustomCursor(this,passCursor);

        notesView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
       notesView.setAdapter(dataCursor);
        notesView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        bar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(bar);

    }
```

Comment: attach the activity onCreate() please

Comment: If you are extending `NoActionBar` theme then don't include `<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>` inside style. You should rather use `Toolbar`.

Comment: @OgnianGloushkov Please see my edited question.

Comment: `You should rather use Toolbar` I did not quite understand.I am using a toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>` from your theme file if you are using a `Toolbar` for a supportActionBar

Comment: I will try your solution and let you know,meanwhile I would like to know as to what themes and styles am I restricted ?

Comment: what do you mean by "restricted" ?

Comment: Restricted means right now I have no idea that which themes will my app support, so how to know which ones I can apply and which ones I cannot apply ?

Comment: I removed that, if you see there is a text over the toolbar. https://i.imgsafe.org/ca26cd8028.png

Comment: set `windowNoTitle` to `true`

Comment: `parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" ` For this attribute how do I know which themes will work and which ones will not ?

Comment: `parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"` For this attribute how do I know which themes will work and which ones will not ?Could you please tell me this.